# How to post Rest API data service from one component to other using react?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, reactjs, post

```
componentDidMount() {
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/UIServices/rest/dataService/postDataConnection?userName=SIVASO',
    data: {
    dataConnectionName: this.state.dataConnectionName,
    dataConnectionType: this.state.dataConnectionType,
    databaseHost: this.state.databaseHost,
    dataConnectionSid: this.state.dataConnectionSid,
  dataConnectionUsername: this.state.dataConnectionUsername,
  dataConnectionPassword: this.state.dataConnectionPassword,
  description: this.state.description,
  connectionMethod: this.state.connectionMethod,
  databasePort: this.state.databasePort,
  jdbcDriver: this.state.jdbcDriver
  }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    self.clearForm()
  })
  .fail(function(jqXhr) {
    console.log('failed to save');
  });
```

}

```
handleSubmit(e){
var self

  e.preventDefault();
  self = this

  console.log(this.state);

  var data = {
    dataConnectionName: this.state.dataConnectionName,
    dataConnectionType: this.state.dataConnectionType,
    databaseHost: this.state.databaseHost,
    dataConnectionSid: this.state.dataConnectionSid,
  dataConnectionUsername: this.state.dataConnectionUsername,
  dataConnectionPassword: this.state.dataConnectionPassword,
  description: this.state.description,
  connectionMethod: this.state.connectionMethod,
  databasePort: this.state.databasePort,
  jdbcDriver: this.state.jdbcDriver
  }
  }

clearForm() {
  this.setState({
    dataConnectionName: "",
    dataConnectionType: "",
    databaseHost: "",
    dataConnectionSid: "",
  dataConnectionUsername: "",
  dataConnectionPassword: "",
  description: "",
  connectionMethod: "",
  databasePort: "",
  jdbcDriver: ""
  });
}
```

I am not able to post the data to the UI after using the post rest service connection can anyone help me out I am working this from last 2 days not able to find any solution. thanks in advance.

I am having all connection detailed to be filled after saving the data should be stored in other component with all the fields in a card format.

After posting i am able to get response in the inspect but not posting the data in the get url

Comment: are you getting data here  `.done(function(data) {
    self.clearForm()
  })`

Comment: No. I am not getting the data

Comment: check your network calls in developer tools. check for your POST request?

Comment: After using the post service the data which are entering in the fields is not displaying but in the inspect it is showing the response code:0 with success response

Comment: self.clearForm() this line is clearing the form? right

Comment: no. not that is created after filling the info the dats will be erased

Comment: i am filling the fields of dataconnectionname and all remaining fields.after filled when i click on save in the responsce it is showing success but that data is not stored in get request